# How to get frames from video from onDraw() of VideoView in Android?

Tags: android, video

This is for video editing. I need to get frames from video files while it's playing and edit them. I found that onDraw() method will be called whenever a new frame is rendered but I don't know how to get frames (get Bitmap from its Canvas) from it.

```
@Override
protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
     super.onDraw(canvas);

     // get frames as Bitmap
     canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap); // UnsupportedOperationException error

}
```

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: check out this link maybe it will help http://android-er.blogspot.com/2013/05/get-current-frame-in-videoview-using.html

Comment: @JRowan it works, but the speed is very slow, it can not be run in real time. maybe because `MediaMetadataReceiver` takes too long time just to seek to the correct position.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this is not working is because you are calling setBitmap after super.onDraw().

Switch your order.

should be:

```
canvas.setBitmap(myBitmap)
super.onDraw(canvas)
```

Comment: This will give the same error. I tried to switch the order already.